# Why is the Zeeman field not time-reversal symmetric?

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

I'm wondering why it is said the the Hamiltonian for a spin-1/2 particle in a magnetic field, $h= \overrightarrow{B} \cdot \overrightarrow{\sigma}$, is not time-reversal symmteric. My understanding is that the magnetic field transforms like $\overrightarrow{B} \to -\overrightarrow{B}$ under time reversal whilst the vector of Pauli matrices transforms like $\overrightarrow{\sigma} \to - \overrightarrow{\sigma}$. So why doesn't the Hamiltonian transform like $h \to h$ rather than $h \to - h$. Moreover, the spin-orbit coupling Hamiltonian, $h = \overrightarrow{\sigma}\cdot \overrightarrow{l}$, is time-reversal symmetric and this seemingly has two components that transform like those of the Zeeman field Hamiltonian. What is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: The difference between the two Hamiltonians is that $\mathbf{B}$ is usually regarded as an external, non-dynamical parameter. This is reasonable when we only consider the time-reversal transformation of the spin, but not including the dynamics of the external source for $\mathbf{B}$ (e.g. solenoid) as part of the system, then $\vec{B}$ does not transform. For spin-orbit coupling, both $\vec{\sigma}$ and $\vec{L}$ are defined on dynamical degrees of freedom, so both of them transform under time reversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start your symmetry analysis, you have to define which system you consider. In this case, do you only consider the spin $1/2$-particle, or do you consider both the particle and the magnetic field along with its source?

If you consider both the particle and the magnetic field along with its source as your system, then yes, the system does have a time-reversal symmetry acting on all components.

If you only consider the particle as your system, then the external magnetic field must be kept invariant under time-reversal symmetry. In that case, the system is not time reversal invariant.

For spin-orbit coupling, the only reasonable choice is to choose the particle as your system. Then both momentum and spin change sign under time reversal.